# deleted one of the administrators in roles which removed the app in facebook developer

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am an administrator of one of the apps on facebook developer account. One of the administrators is obsolete so i decided to remove him from that role. After ticking the (x) on his account to remove the administrator i was kicked out to the main page of the facebook and i cant see the app i was working on again.

i checked if it was deleted so i can restore it back, but it wasnt. what did i do wrong and how can i get the app back? my mobile apps are connected to it for validation.

please help!

thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

really not sure why people are down voting this question, its something i encountered from facebook, but thanks anyways. The solution was that i had to ask another administrator to add me back.

i just want people to know that deleting an administrator could cause you to be deleted from the specific app.

cheers!